Mom believes husband is involving son in satanic rituals
Blonde mommy marries News Hunk who she believes is involving their son in Satanic rituals. At some point, she drowns the boy herself. She's in the hospital and the boy's funeral is a major TV event which happens on Easter Sunday and of course the little devil is resurrected in front of the whole world. The mother and a Preacher who got involved along the way hit the road and know they have to fight the forces of evil. The priest throws his collar out the car window. Creepy motorcycle guy that's been around through the movie picks up the collar and puts it on and the forces of evil have triumphed for now.

This is The Calling from 2000:

A young American woman gets married with a famous British newscaster, and apparently lives a perfect life in the Isle of Man until she discovers that his husband is part of a satanic cult trying to start the Antichritst's reign over Earth. [...] it is up to her to save the soul of her son Dylan (Alex Roe) who plays the role of hateful evil kid perfectly.

She's forced to drown her son, but he's resurrected in his funeral on live TV. And in the end:

As they drive away, Father Mullin removes his collar, kisses it, and throws it out the window of the moving car. It is picked up by a man on a motorcycle who is following them--the same man that came to Kristie's door with the professor's head.

Here's the trailer:



